# Is there any way to import content from SQL to wordpress in wp-admin panel?

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a MySQL database file from my older WordPress website, and I want to import just the content to my new website. Right now, I don't have access to cPanel. Can I import the content using wp importer, or a plugin?

Comment: From which posts do you want to import content?

Comment: @GovindSoni , posts from my older website. I have the sql database which I have imported in xampp phpmyadmin. I want to mport wp-post(from sql db) to wordpress website

Comment: If you want complete data then you should import whole database into the new database, so you can each of data in your new wordpress site

Comment: @GovindSoni: my impression is that Futa doesn't want to import plugin data, settings, users, themes, etc. Just the pages and posts content. If that's the case, importing the entire file would create a mess, and could break any new setup already configured.

Comment: Do you have access to the old website? If so, it would be easiest to simply export just the pages and posts that you want, then import that. I believe there is a tool to do just that from the (tools ?) menu on the dashboard. There are also plugins you could install on both sites to help you out.  If you just have the file, and want to only import posta/pages, you may need to run a query on the MySQL file to extract just the info you do want to import.  Also, know that SO has a sister site dedicated to WordPress questions: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note too, you would need to update any urls from the old sql file to match the new url, if it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have wordpress data then creating a plugin is not good idea.

Simple open your old admin dashboard,

Export the data for either post or pages.

Import in new website using WP Importer.

Comment: I can't open my old website, I have sql file of that website. Right now I'm importing sql file in xampp phpmyadmin and copying wp_post table data to my site. But is there any easy way to do it, like using a plugin where I can import my wp_post table and I get my articles into my new website.

Comment: you can use the same method I suggest you